# tcolorbox text size and horizontal-centering

Tags: tcolorbox

I am learning LaTeX and tcolorbox and trying to recreate the following table from a burger menu.
I am unsure how to horizontally-center the text and change the size of the text inside the top and bottom sections of the tcolorbox to match the original. I also need to know how to set the dimensions of the tcolorbox. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin={1cm,1cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{black}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{beige}{RGB}{254,248,241}


\begin{document}

\section{Colored boxes}


\includegraphics{image002.png}


\tcbset{
        enhanced,
        colback=black!5!beige,
        boxrule=1.5pt,
        colframe=black!75!black,
        fontupper=\large,
        fontlower=\small
       }

       \begin{tcolorbox}[title=CHEESE BURGER \$11.50 - \$14 DOUBLE,   
       lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}%
       {black!50!beige}]
       BLACKWOOD VALLEY ORGANIC GRASS FED BEEF PATTIE WITH SMOKED MOZZARELLA, AMERICAN CHEDDAR, KETCHUP \& MUSTARD
       \end{tcolorbox}



\end{document}
```

[image: First image is an embedded jpeg, second is my attempt to render in tcolorbox]

After some help and more tweaking it's looking closer:

[image: update]

updated code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin={1cm,1cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{black}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{beige}{RGB}{254,248,241}


\begin{document}

\section{Colored boxes}


\includegraphics{image002.png}


\tcbset{
        enhanced,
        colback=black!5!beige,
        boxrule=1.5pt,
        colframe=black!75!black,
        arc=2mm,
        top=3mm,
        width=11.5cm,
        fonttitle=\Large
        }

       \begin{tcolorbox}[center title, title=CHEESE BURGER \$11.50 - \$14 DOUBLE,   
       lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}%
       {black!50!beige}]
       BLACKWOOD VALLEY ORGANIC GRASS FED BEEF PATTIE WITH SMOKED MOZZARELLA, AMERICAN CHEDDAR, KETCHUP \& MUSTARD
       \end{tcolorbox}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the option `center title`, and the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin={1cm,1cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{black}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{beige}{RGB}{254,248,241}


\begin{document}

\section{Colored boxes}



\tcbset{
        enhanced,
        colback=black!5!beige,
        boxrule=1.5pt,
        colframe=black!75!black,
        fontupper=\large,
        fontlower=\small
       }

       \begin{tcolorbox}[
center title,
title=CHEESE BURGER \$11.50 - \$14 DOUBLE,   
       lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}%
       {black!50!beige}]
       BLACKWOOD VALLEY ORGANIC GRASS FED BEEF PATTIE WITH SMOKED MOZZARELLA, AMERICAN CHEDDAR, KETCHUP \& MUSTARD
       \end{tcolorbox}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I need to center the text inside the body as well. Is there a way to do this? It may  happen naturally if I can make the text of the title larger too. I tried with fontupper=\large inside the tcbset but that didn't appear to work. I was also experimenting with trying to use \newline after "PATTIE WITH" but that doesn't appear to work with tcolorbox.

Comment: I used width=11.5cm, under the tcbset and now it looks closer: I will update the question.

Comment: @caston You can add `before upper=\centering`.